# Find PMF and Expected Value of Discrete Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

P(X=x)= $\frac{c}{1+x^2}$; where x=0,±1,±2,±3

find pmf and expected value:

1)

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    -1, & \text{if $x<0$}.\\
    0, & \text{if x=0}.\\1, & x>1
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

2) g(X)= cos($\frac{\pi}{2}$X)

Confused on notation of problem and how to start it.

Comment: well i know c= 5/13

Answer (score 2):

Given $\mathsf P(X=x) = c\,(1+x^2)^{-1}\;\big[x\in\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}\big]$

Well, that *is* the probability mass function; all you need to find is $c$, and do that by using: $$1=\sum\limits_{x\in\{-3,..,3\}}\mathsf P(X=x)$$

---

(a) Given $f(x) = \begin{cases}-1&:& x<0\\0&:& x=0\\1&:& x>0\end{cases}$

- Then $\displaystyle\mathsf E(f(x)) ~{= \sum_{x=-3}^3 f(x)~\mathsf P(X=x)\\ = \sum_{x=-3}^{-1} (-1)\mathsf P(X=x)+0+\sum_{x=1}^3 \mathsf P(X=x) \\~\\ = \ldots \\ ~ }$

  - Hint: $\mathsf P(X=x)=\mathsf P(X=-x)$

---

(b) Given $g(x)= \cos(\pi x/2)$ then $$g(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &:& x\in\{-3,-1,1,3\}\\ 1& : & x=0\\ -1&:& x\in \{-2,2\} \\ \cos(\pi x/2) & :& \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

- $\displaystyle\mathsf E(g(X))~{= \sum_{x=-3}^3 g(x)\, \mathsf P(X=x) \\~\\ = \ldots}$